# ¿Porqué no funciona el segue?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Soy nuevo en stack overflow y en swift. Estoy haciendo una aplicación
de recetas de cocina y una de las funciones es mostrar ciertas recetas que contengan el ingrediente seleccionado(**ingredientDetailViewController**).

Lo que quiero es que a su vez al seleccionar, de una descripción de la receta con la preparación. Ya tengo una vista que hace esto con un **singleton(DetailViewController)** y pensaba reutilizarla pero no consigo que funcione. El caso es que no consigo pasar los datos de **arrayingrediente** de una vista a otra, cuando hago un debug me aparece:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) y
>   fatal error: Index out of range

**Código de ingredientDetailViewController:**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath=tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "idetailrecipe", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

        if (segue.identifier=="idetailrecipe"){
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                let viewController=segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                viewController.arrayingrediente[indexPath.row]=arrayingrediente[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
```

**Código de DetailViewController:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell") as! DetailTableViewCell
        if arrayingrediente.isEmpty{
        cell.titulo?.text=receta?.titulo
        if let image=receta?.imagen{
            cell.imagen?.image=UIImage.init(named:image)
        }
        cell.ingredientes?.text=receta?.ingrediente
        cell.preparacion?.text=receta?.preparacion
        }
        else{
            cell.titulo?.text=arrayingrediente[indexPath.row].titulo
            cell.imagen?.image=UIImage.init(named:arrayingrediente[indexPath.row].imagen)
            cell.ingredientes?.text=arrayingrediente[indexPath.row].ingrediente
            cell.preparacion?.text=arrayingrediente[indexPath.row].preparacion
        }
        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si el error es Index out of range es que estas haciendo referencia a un elemento de un array que se sale del limite. No especificas donde da el error, pero casi seguro que es cuando asignas el arrayingrediente. En DetailViewController tienes un array de ingredientes? y que contiene? los mismo que tienes en ingredientDetailViewController? si es que no, casi seguro que esta dando error en esta línea

```
viewController.arrayingrediente[indexPath.row]=arrayingrediente[indexPath.row]
```

No entiendo muy bien que haces. Le estas diciendo que en el array de viewcontroller, en la posición x de ese array ponga el ingrediente que se ha seleccionado en ingredientDetailViewController, pero ¿qué pasa si en viewcontroller.arrayingrediente solo tienes 3 elementos y le intentas asignar el elemento 8 de tu controlador ingredientDetailViewController? pues que esta intentando acceder al elemento 8 cuando solo tiene 3 y ahí peta. Si lo que quieres es que el ingrediente que has seleccionado aparezca en el nuevo controlador, debes añadirlo al array del DetailViewController, y que se coloque donde tenga que hacerlo. Eso lo haces cambiando la línea de la asignación con esto otro:

```
viewController.arrayingrediente.append(arrayingrediente[indexPath.row])
```

De todas formas si quieres pasar información de un controlador al otro es casi como lo tienes hecho. En el controlador destino tienes que crear propiedades que vana recibir lo que quieras enviar, por ejemplo, quiero pasar un nombre, una edad y un array de comidas favoritas. En el controlador origen tender:

```
var nombre: String = "Pepe"
var edad: Int = 30
var favoritas:[String] = ["carne","Pescado","Flan"]
```

En el controlador destino tienes que tener algo similat, por ejemplo noombre2, edad2 y favoritas2. Cuando llegue el perform segue haces algo parecido a lo que tienes

```
if (segue.identifier=="idetailrecipe"){
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let viewController=segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            viewController.nombre2 = nombre
            viewControlle.edad2 = edad
            viewController.favoritas2 = favoritas
        }
    }
```

Si además imaginamos que el ultimo elemento de las comidas favoritas es el postre, podría pasar solo eso a una propiedad por ejemplo llamada postre que fuera

```
viewControlle.postre = favoritas.last
```

Espero que te haya ayudado, creo que esto era lo que estabas preguntando, si es que no coméntalo

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Si, el error me daba cuando asignaba el arrayingrediente